# Grails-Gradle Integration Test Issue

Tags: grails, gradle, integration-testing, spock, dbunit

We've got this pickle while running integration tests throu Gradle. 
We are using dbunit and Spock.

For some reason, the dynamically added trait methods to the domain class just aren't there, which causes a MissingProperty exception to be thrown.

While running it from inside IntelliJ, JUnit correctly applies the trait methods to the domain class. Also, if we add a @TestFor(*whatever*), then it all works fine. My guess is that the whole Grails App is being loaded in the other cases, or something like that.

Anybody ever had some issue like that? Any insights will be appreciated.

Here are some snippets of what we are trying to accomplish:

This is the domain class:

```
package b.c.c.e

import b.c.c.e.conferencia.Conferencia
import b.c.w.d.SerializableDomain

class Endereco implements SerializableDomain, EnderecoFinder {
  String endereco
  String enderecoCompleto
  Endereco enderecoPai
  String descricao
  Boolean permiteEntrada
  Boolean permiteRetirada
  Boolean disponivelVenda
  Estoque estoque
  Boolean raiz
  Boolean folha
  Set filhos

  static hasMany = [
    filhos      : Endereco,
    lpns        : Lpn,
    conferencias: Conferencia
  ]

  static constraints = {
    endereco shared: "required", maxSize: 100
    enderecoCompleto shared: "required", maxSize: 1000
    descricao maxSize: 1000
    permiteEntrada shared: "required"
    permiteRetirada shared: "required"
    disponivelVenda shared: "required"
    raiz shared: "required"
    folha shared: "required"
  }

  @Override
  String toString() {
    "$enderecoCompleto"
  }
}
```

This is the Trait, it's from a Finder layer which we've placed inside grails-app folder (not sure if that might be an issue).

```
package b.c.c.e

import b.c.c.e.conferencia.StatusConferencia
import org.hibernate.sql.JoinType

trait EnderecoFinder {
  static namedQueries = {
    obterFilhos { id ->
      enderecoPai {
        eq "id", id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the test Spec:

```
package b.c.c.e.endereco

import b.c.c.e.CategoriaEstoque
import b.c.c.e.Endereco
import b.c.c.e.conferencia.StatusConferencia
import b.c.w.g.test.LoadDataSet
// This LoadDataSet is an AST transformation we apply to cleanup the database after each feature.
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.Rollback
import spock.lang.Specification

@Integration
@Rollback
@LoadDataSet("0_5_Enderecos")
class EnderecoFinderIntegrationSpec extends Specification {
  def "#obterFilhos: Obtém os nós que são descendentes diretos de um dado endereço"() {
    setup:
      def enderecoPaiId = 1L

    when: "Executado o método list no critério obterFilhos da entidade Endereco"
      // MissingProperty exception thrown here
      def filhos = Endereco.obterFilhos(enderecoPaiId).list()


    then: "São listados todos os endereços cujo pai é o endereco do id informado"
      filhos.each {
        it.enderecoPai.id == enderecoPaiId
      }
  }
}
```